# Crash appears on a member variable that is null despite Gson converter that never returns null: impossible case

Tags: android

In my Activity, I have a Training object member initialized during onCreate(). **All the members of this object are set.**

`private Training mTraining;` is a class member

```
public class Training extends BaseModel {

    ...

    @SerializedName("state")
    public TrainingState state;

    ....

    public TrainingPreview() {
    }
```

This object is got from server (JSON), and I had a converter on this state to **ensure this enum can't be null** (I use GSON engine):

```
public class TrainingStateConverter extends EnumConverter<TrainingState> {

    public static final Type TYPE = new TypeToken<TrainingState>() {}.getType();

    @Override
    protected TrainingState deserialize(String value) {
        return TrainingState.fromString(value);
    }

    @Override
    protected TrainingState getUnknownValue() {
        return TrainingState.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

During the setup, I've created the exercise list with the listener to show a specific exercise:

```
private void refreshExercisesList() {
        final Runnable showTrainingParts = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int nbItems = mCardExercises.setExercises(mTraining.training, mTraining.state,
                        new FlatCardTrainingProfilePartExercisesView.OnClickExerciseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void showPart(String trainingPartId, int index) {
                                onClickOnExercisesList(trainingPartId, index);
                            }
                        });
            }
        };
    }
   ...
}
```

My onClickOnExercisesList() method:

```
private void onClickOnExercisesList(String trainingPartId, int index) {
        ...

            switch (mTraining.state) {
                ...
```

This Activity code works perfectly since couple of months, but yesterday there was a NullPointerException on `switch (mTraining.state)` :

```
int com.xxx.model.training.TrainingState.ordinal()' on a null object reference
com.xxx.ui.training.TrainingActivity.onClickOnExercisesList
```

How is possible guys?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you are storing it as a global variable, then it is stored on memory and in rare case, the OS is trying to claim back some resources which results in `mTraining = null`. This is a guess from my experience.

Comment: It's not mTraining at null, it's the ".state" in this case...

Comment: @HaiderMalik : it's not a stupid question man, respect please. If you read correctly my question, it's not mTraining it's the member "state" into mTraining.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read the error log carefully, so could you post your `Training` and `TrainingState` code?

Comment: @anthony can you please post the constructor of `Training` class?

Comment: @MustansarSaeed: I've updated my initial post

Comment: @anthony: Is this crash being reproduced? If this is the case then please check at this point what is the state of other member variables of `Training`?  Ithink those will also be `null` at this stage.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed : no I can't reproduce it! It's crazy this crash

Comment: @anthony: Please try to reproduce this. One suggestion for reproducing the crash is: multiple times press home screen and launch app using Recents screen quickly. Its related to loading the objects in a fast manner which device is not handling it quickly in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This would occur if `state` did not appear in the JSON.

The `TypeConverter` is only used if there is a value in the JSON to convert.  If the value isn't present, then there's nothing to convert, so the value is whatever the default is, which is null, because you didn't set it:

```java
    @SerializedName("state")
    public TrainingState state;
```

To fix the issue, initialize the variable to a default value:

```java
    @SerializedName("state")
    public TrainingState state = TrainingState.UNKNOWN;
```